# Jersey Migration from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: json, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

We are migrating our project from jersey 1.X version to 2.X .

```
public static Filter buildFilter(String s) throws Exception {      
JSONJAXBContext context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(),FilterModel.class);   
JSONUnmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createJSONUnmarshaller();   
FilterModel model = unmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(new StringReader(s),
FilterModel.class);      
return model.build();      
  }
```

So my question is how we can do the changes and compatible the above code to Jersey 2.X ?

Thanks advance.

Comment: The equivalent would be to just register the JacksonFeature, given you have jersey-media-json-jackson dependency

Comment: Thats great bro, so how can I convert this line JsonjaxbContext context = new JsonjaxbContext (MoxyjsonConfig.natura().build().modelClasses).... and JsonUnmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createJsonMarshaller() ; unmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(buyeStream,modelClass); ....?

Comment: I have changed my question so that others can get more clarity on it.